# Joomla User creation hooks

Tags: php, joomla, hook

Is it possible to create a hook when a user creates an account?

I have googled and found some stuff on hooks and joomla but nothing really concrete.

Anyone knows if this is possible? Or do I really have to mess with the code. I just want to create code that is upgrade safe.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You're going to write an [user plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla_1.5) based on [user events for plugin system](http://docs.joomla.org/Reference:User_Events_for_Plugin_System). From your question I believe you want [onAfterStoreUser](http://docs.joomla.org/Reference:User_Events_for_Plugin_System#5.3.7_onAfterStoreUser) or [onBeforeStoreUser](http://docs.joomla.org/Reference:User_Events_for_Plugin_System#5.3.6_onBeforeStoreUser) event hooks. Check these provided links for official documentation with examples.

Comment: Thanks!! This seems to be exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: The user-plugin link -- http://developer.joomla.org/tutorials/184-how-to-create-a-joomla-plugin.html -- has died from bit-rot. This might be it, or similar: http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla_1.5